# Java while loop print "+" based on the input of variable x

Tags: java, while-loop

I want to be able to make a statement that prints (in this case "+") based upon the input of variable x. Example: If someone writes that x = 3, then it should print out "+++".

```
public static void runLoop(int x){
    
    while(//Code//){
        System.out.print("+");
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried?  This just seems like a homework problem you haven't attempted yet.

Comment: Not sure if this is the kind of answer you are looking for, but it seems to me a `for` loop would be more idiomatic and clear.

Comment: It is an excercise, but I tried around a lot but could'nt find any information plus i figured that I would learn more if I just asked the question and didn't search around for several hours just for a simple answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want `while` loop and not `for` loop you may do this:

```
public static void runLoop(int x){
    
    while(x--!=0){
        System.out.print("+");
    }
}
```

Explanation : 
the `x--` return the current value of x and only then decrease it by one so the code will be executed `x` times.

NOTE: 
`x--` overrides  `x` value so if you want to keep the value simply use a temporary variable.

Comment: Well thank you, tried it with only  x != 0, missed out the "--" so thank you!